# Rails: different layouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my app I want to use different layouts when user is logged in and not

application_controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  layout :determine_layout

  private

    def determine_layout
      user_signed_in? ? 'application' : 'landing'
    end

end
```

But this code not working: layouts not changing. Could Devise cause this? Or some mistakes I made?

Thanks!

Comment: code looks ok, which is the layout you always have?

Comment: when user is logged in it's `application` and when user isn't logged in layout it's `landing`

Comment: ok so your method works...

Comment: Check if `user_signed_in?` returning false when you are logged out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was going to write as comment, but it will be easier to process here:

According to the [Devise github wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Create-custom-layouts), you could determine whether it's based on `devise_controller` or not:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout :layout_by_resource

  protected

  def layout_by_resource
    if devise_controller?
      "layout_name_for_devise"
    else
      "application"
    end
  end
end
```

This would allow you to point the user to `sessions#landing` if they weren't logged in, which would mean creating a new action in a custom Devise sessions controller

This would DRY-up the process of determining if they are logged-in or not (if they are not logged in, they can see static views from the `session` or `registrations` controllers of Devise